# How implement a listener to a EJB Asynchronous call

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6

I have a web application deployed in Jboss 6. I'm using  JDK 6, jSF and Primefaces.

I have a method in my business layer which takes a long time to complete.
I want to be able to show in the web page a log of what the method is doing. Here is a simplified version of what im trying:

```java
/* interface to log processing */

interface StatusListener {
    void log(String msg);
}

/* Business class */ 

@Stateless    
class Service {

     @Asynchronous
     public void doProcessing(StatusListener listener) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ ) {
           processItem(i);
           listener.log("processando item " + n);
        }
     }
}

/* JSF backing bean class */

@Named
public class WebBean implements StatusListener {

     private @EJB Service service; 
     private StringBuffer msgBuffer;

     public void doProcessing() {
        service.doProcessing(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void log(String msg) {
         msgBuffer.append(msg + "\n");
     }

     public StringBuffer getMsgBuffer() {
         return msgBuffer;
     }

}
```

In my XHTML I have a `textArea` whose value points to the `msgBuffer`. I use primefaces poll to update the `textArea` every few seconds.
The problem is the `msgBuffer` is only updated after the ejb method finishes. The log method is called, but the changes to the `msgBuffer` are only visible to the web bean thread after the ejb finishes. I have tried making `msgBuffer` volatile and synchonized the log and `getMsgBuffer` methods, but didn't work.
Anyone have any clue how to solve this?